# Can throw be used instead of break in a switch statement?

Tags: java, oop, exception, throw

Can throw also be used to exit switch statement without using break keyword? Why use a throw instead of break?

```
switch(number)
{
    case 1:
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception number 1");
    case 2:     
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception number 2"); 
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't. Exceptions should never be used for controlling the flow. Use exceptions for exceptions. If an exception occurs inside the switch, then it's fine.

Comment: Because you are being paid by the number of characters you type

Comment: The one reasonably standard place you might throw inside a switch statement is in the default case.  If reaching that case indicates invalid input, then it's reasonable to throw an exception.

Comment: There is nothing special about switch statements with regards to exceptions. The reasons for throwing exceptions are the same as in other code.

Answer (score 12):

There are two cases in which you could use a `throw` to interrupt the flow of a switch:

1. **Flow Control**; in general, this is a *bad* practice - you don't want exceptional behavior deciding where your program decides to go next.
2. **Unlikely-but-plausible default case**; in case you hit a condition in which reaching the default *should* be impossible, but happens anyway.  Somehow.  Miraculously.  Or, if you have strict coding standards, which mandate that switch statements have a default case.

   Example:

   ```
   public class Test {
       public static enum Example {
           FIRST_CASE,
           SECOND_CASE;
       }
       public void printSwitch(Example theExampleCase) {
           switch(theExampleCase) {
               case FIRST_CASE:
                   System.out.println("First");
                   break;
               case SECOND_CASE:
                   System.out.println("Second");
                   break;
               default:  // should be unreachable!
                   throw new IllegalStateException(
            "Server responded with 724 - This line should be unreachable");
        }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

I see some reasons for throw in a switch statement.

1st: not instead of a break but as the body of the `default` case. Consider the following example where a switch is defined on an enumeration:

```
pubic enum E {
  A,
  B
}
```

The switch as of the time as it is first written looks like:

```
E e = ...;
switch (e) {
  case A:
    ...
    break;
  case B:
    ...
    break;
  default:
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown enumeration value " + e);
}
```

The throw is a fallback for future extensions to the enumeration `E`.

2nd: Sometimes I have where small getter functions, for example in the Swing table model. There I use return instead of break;

```
public String getColumnName(int col)
{
  switch (col)
  {
    case 0: return "Column 0";
    case 1: return "Column 1";
    ...
```

This is for the sake of brevity or compactness. One may say that these returns break the control flow. This is true. However, I think that for compactness reasons it might be allowed here.

If you accept `return` instead of a `break` in this case you may accept `throw` too here.

```
Object[] x = ...; // get some array which is not null from a function which
                  // only returns arrays, e.g. OSGI services
switch (x.length)
{
  case 0: throw new IllegalArgumentException("No service defined");
  case 1: return x[0]; // return the only available service
  default:
    ... // evaluate all services and return the best matching one
    return x[...];
}
```

Comment: I tend to agree with this.  If you cover all possible cases in the switch "case" sections, then why not throwing an exception in the "default" section to first indicate the incoming parameter is wrong and second to safeguard against future expansion of the switch construction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `throw` in `switch` block but its not good coding/design practice. `throw` is meant to control exceptional/error situation in code not for controlling execution of instructions.

Eventhough you can use `throw` in `switch` , I would recommded not to use it in `switch`. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about only one scenario, where you need to throw the exception. switch is designed to run a case and break it. If it is in a method and if you only use throw then how will you return a value from that method?
In simple terms throw will return the method but break will not. You can continue running your code after the switch with break but not with throw.

Answer (score 0):

break is used to prevent falling thru to the next case, when you throw an exception there will be no falling thru

```
    case 1:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        break;   <-- compile error, unreachable code
```

It typically makes sense to throw an exception in otherwise clause

```
    switch (op) {
    case 1:
        // do something 
        break;
    ...
    default:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

There are few problems using throw instead of break;

1)when you throw some Exception the execution of rest of the function stops.

ie:

```
int m=0;
    switch (m) {
    case 0:
        y=10;
        break;
    case 2:
        y=11;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(y);//this y will never be printed if Exceptions are thrown
```

2) Exceptions generally represent some error condition,and switch not every time should create exception.

3) To get the value "Exception number 1" from

```
throw new RuntimeException("Exception number 1");
```

you have to wright catch block and call e.getMessage();

like:

```
catch(RuntimeException e){
        String str=e.getMessage();
    }
```

this is even more overhead and also the data you can pass is only String Object.

Conclusion:-
Its better to use normal break.

Answer (score -1):

throw Can not  be used instead of break in a switch statement. because throw is just used for exceptions while switch is used for conditional purposes...

Comment: You can use `throw` in addition to `return` or `break` in a `switch`, since all three of them complete abruptly (that is, return control to somewhere other than the currently running method).